# React testing with enzyme : Setting value for inner component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am writing test cases using enzyme and jest of for a React component. The definition of my react component goes like

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    
    
  // some code here
    
  showModalandSetValues () {
      //some code here
    this.confirmModal.setFormValues (values);
    
  }
    
  render (){
    const {val1 , val2} = this.props
    
    return <div>
      // some more markup
      <MyForm>
        <MyModal ref = {ref => this.confirmModal = ref}} />
      </MyForm>
    </div>
  }  
}

export default MyComponent
```

I am using shallow method of enzyme. How can I set the value of this.confirmModal in test ? It only gets set through render method . Kindly advice.

Answer (score 0):

[they says](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/316) refs are not set in `shallow()`.

You can use `mount()` but mock subcomponents to achieve semi-shallow rendering:

```
import MyModal from '../some/path/MyModal.js'; // to be able to .find(MyModal)

// modal is rendered as a span
jest.mock('../some/path/MyModal.js', () => (props) => <span {...props} />);

...
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
```